# How speed up overflow auto

Tags: javascript, css, html, performance

I have 10000 items on page.

```
<body> /*10000 items*/ </body>
```

All works good if items in body (on scroll is not lag, because this is browser's scroll).

But if I'am using `<div>` with css `overflow:auto` on scroll It's very lag.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height: 1000px;"> /*10000 items*/ </div>
```

Why this happend and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: can u put it in js fiddle?

Comment: no, because there is overflow:auto too. Good works only in body.

Comment: Have you tried : overflow: visible ?

Comment: Why not lazy loading the data? Or use pagination? That might speed things up.

Comment: I need to show items in div with scroll. If I'using overflow: visible then scroll disappear

Comment: My bad, use : overflow: scroll;

Comment: It's not called "overflow: auto". It's called a scrollbar. If you want to improve scrolling performance, reduce the number of items to scroll. Saying you want to improve the performance of the overflow property implies it has anything to do with that property - it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I want. @ArchNoob.

Comment: I think the fact that you load 10,000 data at once and render them kinda impacts the performance. Just like what @BoltClock is saying.

Comment: @ArchNoob perhaps you are rigth. But Why normal scroll browser to show 10000 items without problem? Only scroll which set overflow: auto lag?

Comment: Not sure, did some search and found this on MDN `/* Let the browser decide */
overflow: auto;
` I would say, Like @BaptisteArnaud said, maybe `overflow: scroll` is more explicit declaration and won't cost on performance. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Thanks but this is lag too.

Comment: upgrade your computer then @Lestoroer

Comment: I have core I7.

Comment: Still: transmitting 10K things means the user has to wait for them, right? That doesn't sound like an user experience that user tolerate in 2017. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In real project into div loads 200 items. Then when user is scrolling, server is added +200 and so to 10000 (+200, +200, +200).But when 10000 items it's very lag

Comment: use the infinite scroll https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/ this loads in data time at time, just like youtube does.